# Database strategy for models that have different versions

Tags: database-design

I'm in the need of creating a database structure where I can have several versions of a certain model. For example, take a car.

```
table: cars
version 1, fields: id, make, model, type
version 2, fields: id, make, model, type, entrance_year, designer
```

I am looking for a way to keep the model flexible, but easy to understand and have the possibility to create a version 1 model of the car, but for someone else a version 2 of the car.

All I could come up with so far is a key/value pair-like database, but that easily gets complicated to follow along. In reality I will have about 100 tables containing 3 to 40 fields with versions that might change at least a few times per year. Whereas the consumer of that data is able to plug in to a specific version of a model.

Are there other designs I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be for your table to have one more column called `version` with the datatype `int`. If a particular version requires additional columns or information, the `cars` table can have a one-to-one foreign key relationship with another table that has the extra columns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't see what's beneficial about that in relation to the vertical key/value design. It would become pretty messy when there are 5 versions for the car table, each containing a few columns that need to be added; also four joins would be necessary.